# Make up of a single web with react

Tags: reactjs

Hello I'm really new with React and webpack and after a few days already manage to set up a functional working environment. Now I'm stuck in design issues since I would like to create a 960 wide grid separated into 12 columns with 15 gutters. Then start by creating a 100% high section where you center an image on an 80% white background versus a red main color. In advance grateful for any help or tip that is offered

Comment: Use a CSS framework that does this for you?

Comment: Have a look at http://getbootstrap.com/ and http://www.material-ui.com/

Answer (score 0):

Many css frameworks would let you do that. you don't need to change your existing toolkit if all you need is grid positioning or basic styles.

Also, you can find a number of react libraries for reusable react components like [React Toolbox](https://github.com/react-toolbox/react-toolbox)

for example If you're already familiar with bootstrap, Take a look at https://react-bootstrap.github.io

Comment: Currently the work environment I have configured uses NodeJs, ReactJs, Webpack, Babylon and dependencies to work with CSS and SCSS. The truth is that I have very little or no experience and I would appreciate some practical example of how to execute the task that I expose.